# Retrieving SVN Commits programmatically, without Atlassian Fisheye

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

We are currently using Atlassian JIRA for defects and regular development cycles. We are using SVN Repository for maintaining the code. One of the recent things that we did was to develop an custom utility using SVNKit 1.7.4 and Atlassian Fisheye which given a list of JIRA id's fetches the commits from SVN. This is done with use of Atlassian Fisheye REST services.Once we get this list of file paths, we compare the working copy with the target and use applyTextDelta method of SVNDeltaGenerator to modify the files and then check-in in the target branch. The single most important thing we require is the changesets from SVN for a particular JIRA ID. Once we give the JIRA ID as input, Fisheye fetches the details from SVN and sends it back as List.

Now, If we need to bypass Fisheye and instead use SVN internal capabilities to achieve the same which Fisheye does for us, what would we need to do? We follow svn hook where the commit message always contains JIRA ID, is there a way we can retrieve the complete change set including filenames, paths, directories that were added with that specific JIRA, say using commit message? One of the sample commit messages used by our Developers is "ND-9181: This file is related to ABC and has fix for DE119919". Here ND-9181 is JIRA ID. Similar all commits to SVN mandatorily has the JIRA ID.

What I want is to specify SVN below:

Find All Files/File Paths/Directories From SVN Where Commit_Msg ='ND-9817'

If anyone has ever achieved this or knows a way of doing this programatically using SVNKit, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Subversion CLI supports a [`--search`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search) option for the `svn log` command since version 1.8, so if using the CLI is an option, you could simply parse the results of this command:

```
svn log -v --search ND-9817
```

Curiously, this feature isn't available in the most recent [SVNKit API](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/) (The Javadocs they provide are for a 1.7 version, but I experimented with the most recent version 1.8.11). Thus, manual filtering seems to be needed for an SVNKit solution. I left out package, imports and main method for brevity.

```java
public class q34800380 {
    public void grepLogMessages(String url, String message) throws SVNException {
        SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
        try {
            SvnLog log = svnOperationFactory.createLog();
            log.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromURL(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url)));
            log.addRange(SvnRevisionRange.create(SVNRevision.create(0), SVNRevision.HEAD));
            log.setDiscoverChangedPaths(true);
            log.setReceiver(new GrepLogReceiver(message));
            log.run();
        } finally {
            svnOperationFactory.dispose();
        }
    }
    private class GrepLogReceiver implements ISvnObjectReceiver<SVNLogEntry> {
        private String message;
        public GrepLogReceiver(String message) {
            this.message = message; 
        }
        @Override
        public void receive(SvnTarget target, SVNLogEntry le) throws SVNException {
            if (le.getMessage() != null && le.getMessage().contains(message)) {
                System.out.println("rev #" + le.getRevision() + ": " + le.getMessage());
                Map<String, SVNLogEntryPath> cps = le.getChangedPaths();
                for (Map.Entry<String, SVNLogEntryPath> e : cps.entrySet()) {
                    SVNLogEntryPath lep = e.getValue();
                    System.out.println(lep.getType() + " " + lep.getPath());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a doable approach. Thanks for helping out. I'll give this class a shot at our requirement. Between, the message String can take JIRA ID as input right as there is "contains" test. Am I correct in understanding it?

Comment: Exactly. You can adjust that test to your liking, e.g. making it case-insensitive or using a more sophisticated matching approach using a regular expression. Also, you will need some mechanism, so that you can access the results from outside `GrepLogReceiver`, this here just prints them to `STDOUT` - I've kept it simple for brevity `:)`